# Limit queried columns based on list set in runtime

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query:

```
// Type T is constrained to a class that contains "ID" property
// propertiesToQuery is a list constructed based on type T
var set = AppContext.Set<T>();
var result = set.SelectMany(x => propertiesToQuery.Select(p => new { x.ID, Value = x.GetType().GetProperty(p.Name).GetValue(x) })
                                                          .Where(p => p.Value != null)
                                                          .Select(p => new SearchIndexItem
                                                                           {
                                                                               Key = p.Value.ToString(),
                                                                               Url = Url.Action("Edit", type.Name, new { p.ID }),
                                                                               Type = type
                                                                           }));
```

Now because linq to entities does not allow to use PropertyInfo in queries, I need to run a ToList() on the set in order to execute the query on the db first and then perform the desired SelectMany().

This queries more than it needs to from the database which will be a problem when there's a lot of data (queried columns are of type string, others can be blobs and these are the ones I don't want to pull the data from)

So the question is how can I limit the columns queried from the db based on a list constructed at runtime?

I was trying to create an expression tree, and pass it to the Select() method on the set, but the problem was with creating the anonymous type, which can be different depenging on type T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation here:

> the problem was with creating the anonymous type, which can be different depenging on type T

is accurate; it is hugely problematic to construct the result *columns* at runtime. The only simply way to do that is to make it look like you are populating a *projection* of a type that has all the members, for example the equivalent of:

```
// where our list is "Foo", "Bar":
x => new SomeType {
   Foo = x.Foo,
   Bar = x.Bar
   // but other SomeType properties exist, but are't mapped
}
```

The obvious contender would be the entity type, so you are partially mapping a set of `Customer` rows to `Customer` objects - but most ORMs won't let you do that: if the projection is an entity type they want the entire type (i.e. `x => x`). You might be able to create a second version of the entity type that is a regular POCO/DTO but isn't part of the entity model, i.e.

```
Customer x => new CustomerDto {
   Foo = x.Foo,
   Bar = x.Bar
}
```

which you can do as part of `Expression.MemberInit` at runtime. Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public DateTime C { get; set; }
}
class FooDto
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public DateTime C { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new[] { new Foo { A = "a", B = 1, C = DateTime.Now}}
                 .AsQueryable();
        var mapped = PartialMap<Foo, FooDto>(data, "A", "C").ToList();
    }
    static IQueryable<TTo> PartialMap<TFrom, TTo>(
        IQueryable<TFrom> source, params string[] members)
    {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFrom));
        var body = Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(typeof(TTo)),
            from member in members
            select (MemberBinding)Expression.Bind(
                typeof(TTo).GetMember(member).Single(),
                Expression.PropertyOrField(p, member))
            );
        return source.Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<TFrom, TTo>>(body, p));
    }
}
```

in the output, `A` and `C` have values, but `B` does not.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting approach. Can I use a proxy/adapter/decorator instead of the dto type or will entity framework detect inheritance and throw an error?

Comment: @Chris don't know - if you find out, let me know

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible :/ but thanks a lot for the idea, I think that i should be able to adjust it to my needs.